# How can I use $(this) in JQuery to animate these images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three thumbnails. When the user moves their mouse over them, i wan't to fade them from partial opacity to full opacity, and back again when their mouse isn't over them any longer.
I have this code which works fine, but it seems redundant to retype all this code for each image. How can I be more efficient in doing this? It seems like a use of $(this) would work but it isn't so far. What am I missing?

```
function imgFade()
{
$('#cluster').fadeTo(0,.3);
$('#launch').fadeTo(0,.3);
$('#gas').fadeTo(0,.3);

}
              $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("#cluster").mouseover(function () {
                           $("#cluster").fadeTo("slow", 1, function () {
                           });
                     });
                     $("#cluster").mouseout(function () {
                           $("#cluster").fadeTo("slow", .3, function () {
                           });
                     });
              });
;
```

Comment: if you tried it you could have figured out, and yes you can use $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be completely rewritten and shortened in this way:

```
function imgFade() {
    $('#cluster, #launch, #gas').fadeTo(0, .3);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cluster")
       .mouseover(function () {
          $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
       })
       .mouseout(function () {
          $(this).fadeTo("slow", .3);
       });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Figured it was something easy

Answer (score 0):

Just use a selector that picks up all three elements:

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
                 $("#cluster, #launch, #gas").fadeTo(0, .3).mouseover(function () {
                       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
                 }).mouseout(function () {
                       $(this).fadeTo("slow", .3);
                 });
          });
```

...and then within the handler `this` will refer to the current element.

Note that you can chain the `.mouseover().mouseout()` functions rather than reselecting the elements with separate calls to `$("#cluster, #launch, #gas")`.

Rather than selecting them by their ids it might be tidier if you gave all similar elements a common class and then select by that: `$(".someClass").mouseover(...`

Note also that there's no point providing an empty callback function to `.mouseover()` - you can just omit that last argument if you don't want to do anything when the fade is complete.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something simple I was missing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
function imgFade()
{
    $('#cluster, #launch, #gas').fadeTo(0,.3);

}
              $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("#cluster, #launch, #gas").mouseover(function () {
                           $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1, function () {
                           });
                     });
                     $("#cluster, #launch, #gas").mouseout(function () {
                           $(this).fadeTo("slow", .3, function () {
                           });
                     });
              });
```

Comment: If the selector is always the same is better to just cache it: var elems = $('#cluster, #launch, #gas');
also you can rely on functions chaining for the second (anonymous) function.

Comment: Yes, I definitely put this out without much thought of optimisation - please forgive me...